# Redirect url to custom url using .htaccess or bootstrap in ZF1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I'm working with Zend Framework 1.9 and facing some problems with the routes. Actually, looking for a way to route url to custom one (url), but unfortunately couldn't find a solution after surfing on internet as well as on Stack Overflow.

Well, the problem is that the defined url is working fine: http://example.com/user/detail/code/hsg45464

but, I want to change the above url to custom url, something like this: http://example.com/[user_name]/[course]/[cource_description]

So, is there any possibility to achieve this custom url in Zend Framework 1.9 (.htaccess or bootstrap).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do it in `Bootstrap.php` instead of changing anything in `config`, `index.php` or `.htaccess`

```
## /application/Bootstrap.php ##

protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute('user-course', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:username/:course/:desc', array(
        'controller' => 'default_controller_name',
        'action' => 'default_action_name'
    )));
}
```

After that you need to create a controller and a view to render it.

Also, you can go through the routing documentation of `Zend Framework 1.9` in detail, so here is the link: [Zend Framework 1.9 Routing](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.controller.router.html)